# MDX Less Than Equal to Filter Expression Not Working

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, sql-server-2016

I have the following MDX query running on SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY(Measures.[Enrolments Count]) ON COLUMNS,                   
                    NON EMPTY FILTER ( [Term Record Creation].[Year].CHILDREN * [Term Record Creation].[Week].CHILDREN *
                        [Term Enrolments].[Term Year].CHILDREN ,
                        [Term Record Creation].[Week]  <= 5)
                     DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
        FROM [Enrolments]
```

I am trying to only take enrolments where a term record was created before week 5 of the year (where the week is an ISO week).

The `Term Year` is the year in which a term starts. It is a column in addition to the term record creation dimensions i.e. `[Term Record Creation].[Year]` and `[Term Record Creation].[Week]`.

The problem I am having is that the filter is doing some sort of filtering (because my measure column is low), but I am still getting all of the weeks of the year with a number against them e.g. I have a row like the following in the result set:

`Creation Year   Creation Week   Term Year   Enrolments Count
       2012             16          2013             4`

I would really appreciate if someone could explain what is going wrong and provide a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try just filtering the week:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Measures.[Enrolments Count] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Term Record Creation].[Year].Children*
      Filter
      (
        [Term Record Creation].[Week].Children
       ,
        [Term Record Creation].[Week] <= 5
      )*
      [Term Enrolments].[Term Year].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Enrolments];
```

Although I think Daylo will be correct in that you'll need to use the key:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Measures.[Enrolments Count] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Term Record Creation].[Year].Children*
      Filter
      (
        [Term Record Creation].[Week].Children
       ,
        [Term Record Creation].[Week].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY <= 5
      )*
      [Term Enrolments].[Term Year].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Enrolments];
```

In our cube a week's key is like this `201709` so this might be better:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Measures.[Enrolments Count] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Term Record Creation].[Year].Children*
      Filter
      (
        [Term Record Creation].[Week].Children
       ,
        Cint([Term Record Creation].[Week].CurrentMember.Member_Caption) <= 5
      )*
      [Term Enrolments].[Term Year].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Enrolments];
```

Ok - the last approach tests fine against a similar script against `AdvWrks`:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,
    [Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory]
  * 
    Filter
    (
      [Date].[Day of Month].[Day of Month]
     ,
      Cint([Date].[Day of Month].CurrentMember.Member_Caption) > 10
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: [Term Record Creation].[Week] <= 5 makes no sense, it won't return a value.

Comment: I think you're correct in terms of it being a value - although whether the key value is simple 1....52 is a seperate issue! In our cube a weeks key is like this `201709`

Comment: So the first one does not work (I get results with a week greater than 5). I am using a composite key of year and week (not concatenated value for the key). For the second answer, I get the stored procedure failed because the string is not in the correct format.

Comment: @fluffybonkers try the third script - it converts the member's caption, which is a string "5" to an integer: I'll edit as looks like I used `Csng` instead of `CInt`

Comment: @whytheq I get a type mismatch error. However, if I use the `CInt` and change `Member_Caption` to `Member_Key` I get the correct results. Thank you so much for your help. However, I would like to know why I need to cast the key as an `int`, considering it is stored in the data source as an `int` and in the SSAS cube?

Comment: @fluffybonkers I find that a little odd for two reasons - Member_Key should work fine without `CInt` but also you mentioned using a composite key - what form does it take? If it is this form "201709" then it is strange that `201709 <= 5` is ever true?!

Answer (score 1):

It won't work:

```
[Term Record Creation].[Week]  <= 5
```

You compare Week hierarchy with number. It doesn't make sense. Try something like the following:

```
Select
[Measures].[Enrolments Count] on columns,                   
Non Empty 
    Filter(
        [Term Record Creation].[Week].[Week].Members,
        Right(
            [Term Record Creation].[Week].CurrentMember.Member_Caption,
            2
        )  <= "05"
    ) *
    [Term Record Creation].[Year].[Year].Members *    
    [Term Enrolments].[Term Year].Children on rows  
From [Enrolments]
```

Comment: `FILTER` against a small set is not the end of the world - for the sake of readability.

Comment: Sure, you're right. It's a habit. I tend to use the FILTER function as little as possible and a small promotion of non-FILTER option won't hurt anyone.

Comment: I have a composite key of year and week. For this answer, I get `The NONEMPTY function expects a tuple set expression for the 2 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.`

Comment: What the format of week key do you have? If it something like '2017-05', you can use the logic above: I've updated the code. I've rewritten it with the Filter function for sake of readability.